# dvilualatex cannot find fonts in fresh install of MacTeX 2017

Tags: mactex

I've repeated the process several times, and it always fails in the same way. I even updated all the packages with TeX Live utility, but the error isn't fixed.

This Mac has a fresh install of Sierra 10.12.6 (formatted the drive for installing 10.12.6 directly), and then did a fresh install of MacTeX 2017 on it.

If I use `latex` everything works fine.

But if I use `dvilualatex` I get the following errors for all input files I tried:

> kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[lmroman17-regular]:+tlig;',
>   contains '[' dvips: Font [lmroman17-regular]:+tlig; not found; using
>   cmr10
>
> dvips: Design size mismatch in font [lmroman17-regular]:+tlig;
>   kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[lmroman12-regular]:+tlig;',
>   contains '[' dvips: Font [lmroman12-regular]:+tlig; not found; using
>   cmr10
>
> dvips: Design size mismatch in font [lmroman12-regular]:+tlig;
>   kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[lmroman12-bold]:+tlig;',
>   contains '[' dvips: Font [lmroman12-bold]:+tlig; not found; using
>   cmr10
>
> dvips: Design size mismatch in font [lmroman12-bold]:+tlig; dvips: !
>   invalid char 205 from font [lmroman12-bold]:+tlig; Error:
>   /undefinedfilename in (/Users/mike/first_test.ps)

I googled for these errors, and they seem to be related to fonts not being installed. However, `latex` can find all fonts, it's only when I use `dvilualatex` when fonts are not found.

I've installed several versions of MacTeX in different Mac OS X versions during the years, and never had to apply any special steps for `dvilualatex` finding fonts.

Is there any extra installation step pending in my MacTeX 2017 installation?

In case you need a MWE, here is one:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\makeindex
\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks]{hyperref} 
\begin{document}
\date{\today}
\title{A M.W.E.}
\author{That's me}
\maketitle
Hello, I'm a MWE.
\end{document}
```

After running `dvilualatex mwe.tex` and then `dvips -o mwe.ps mwe.dvi`, I get the following errors (and no output is generated)

> This is dvips(k) 5.997 Copyright 2017 Radical
>   Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com) ' LuaTeX output 2017.07.27:2018' ->
>   mwe.ps kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname
>   `[lmroman17-regular]:+tlig;', contains '[' dvips: Font
>   [lmroman17-regular]:+tlig; not found; using cmr10
>
> dvips: Design size mismatch in font [lmroman17-regular]:+tlig;
>   kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[lmroman12-regular]:+tlig;',
>   contains '[' dvips: Font [lmroman12-regular]:+tlig; not found; using
>   cmr10
>
> dvips: Design size mismatch in font [lmroman12-regular]:+tlig; dvips:
>   ! invalid char 8217 from font [lmroman12-regular]:+tlig;

Comment: The comparison is wrong: latex searches for type1-fonts in the texmf-tree, lualatex for open-/truetype-fonts in the system's font directory.

Comment: Looks like the set of fonts LuaTeX uses by default (Latin Modern family) are incompatible with DVI viewer. So, I guess, don't use LuaTeX with DVI output format.

Comment: I've been using `dvilualatex` since MacTeX 2012 in SnowLeopard, and updated both to newer MacTeX and Mac OS X versions over the years, and, as I far as I can remember, I never had to install any additional fonts, just the main MacTeX `pkg`. In fact, `dvilualatex` worked fine on MacTeX 2016 with a default ElCapitan install. BTW, Sergei, I really need to go through DVI because of how my pipeline works. I cannot go to PDF directly.

Comment: Edited to add MWE and its output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the newest latex format lualatex uses the TU encoding and so open type fonts that dvips can't handle. You can switch to another fontencoding (OT1 or T1) like this:

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\makeindex
\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\date{\today}
\title{A M.W.E.}
\author{That's me}
\maketitle
Hello, I'm a MWE.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I marked your answer as the accepted one because it also reminded me that I should be using `\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}`in all documents that are not expected to be in an unicode environment, and I've been omitting that line for years.

Answer (score 2):

As outlined in [LaTeX News 26](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews26.pdf), the team have switched the standard encoding for Unicode engines (XeTeX and LuaTeX) from OT1 to TU, and as-standard this means that Latin Modern is loaded with these engines. This means that OpenType font files are used out-of-the box, and aligns with the most common use case for these engines. If you need to avoid this, the `latexrelease` package can be used to revert

```
\RequirePackage[2015/12/31]{latexrelease}
```

To date, most DVI tools have not been updated to work with system fonts: this is somewhat frustrating but likely reflects the fact that very few people use LuaTeX without also using PDF output. (There are issues with using OT1/T1 encoded fonts with a Unicode engine, which is why the change has been made.)

Comment: I guess that `dvips` is one of the tools that are not ready for UT. Thanks a lot for your procedure for reverting to the previous behaviour, I find it complementary to Ulrike FIsher's answer, but in this particular case I prefer to enforce T1 encoding rather than reverting, because I need that my TeX source is portable across different MacTeX versions without changes, so enforcing T1 seems a more compatible approach.